# New newtxtext bug: Incomplete \ifx

Tags: errors, bugs, newtx

After the latest updates to packages with TeX Live 2021, package `newtxtext` ceases to work.

Example source:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}

\begin{document}
Hello, world!
\end{document}
```

From the log:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.22 (TeX Live 2021) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2021.5.17)  22 MAY 2021 15:28
entering extended mode
 \write18 enabled.
 file:line:error style messages enabled.
 %&-line parsing enabled.
**newtxbug.tex
(./newtxbug.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 4
L3 programming layer <2021-05-11>
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo
File: size10.clo 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
:
:
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/newtxtext.sty
Package: newtxtext 2021/05/16 v1.65

`newtxtext' v1.65, 2021/05/16 Text macros taking advantage of TeX-Gyre Termes f
onts (msharpe) (/Users/murray/Library/texmf/tex/latex/MinionPro/fontaxes.sty
Package: fontaxes 2007/03/31 v0.2b Font selection axes
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 26.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 28.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 30.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \swshape on input line 32.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 34.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \sscshape on input line 36.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \ulcshape on input line 38.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textsw on input line 43.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textssc on input line 44.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \textulc on input line 45.
)
\ntx@fs=\dimen139

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/xkeyval/xkeyval.sty
Package: xkeyval 2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkeyval.tex
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/xkvutils.tex
\XKV@toks=\toks15
\XKV@tempa@toks=\toks16

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xkeyval/keyval.tex))
\XKV@depth=\count187
File: xkeyval.tex 2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
))
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/etoolbox/etoolbox.sty
Package: etoolbox 2020/10/05 v2.5k e-TeX tools for LaTeX (JAW)
\etb@tempcnta=\count188
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/generic/xstring/xstring.tex
\integerpart=\count189
\decimalpart=\count190
)
Package: xstring 2019/02/06 v1.83 String manipulations (CT)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty
Package: ifthen 2014/09/29 v1.1c Standard LaTeX ifthen package (DPC)
)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/carlisle/scalefnt.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty
Package: fontenc 2020/08/10 v2.0s Standard LaTeX package
LaTeX Font Info:    Trying to load font information for T1+ntxtlf on input line
 112.

(/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtlf.fd
File: t1ntxtlf.fd 2021/05/07 v1.1 font definition file for T1/ntx/tlf
)
! Incomplete ifx; all text was ignored after line 3.
<inserted text> 
                fi 
l.112 ...\familydefault\seriesdefault\shapedefault
                                                  
?
```

(The source file is named `newtxbug.tex`.)

Comment: A possible bug in file `t1ntxtlf.fd`? If you move this line of code: `\global\newif\ifntx@sl\global\ntx@sltrue%` before the one that precedes, the error disappears

Comment: As Ivan said, it's a bug with `t1ntxtlf.fd`. The mentioned line should read `\global\expandafter\newif\csname ifntx@sl\endcsname\global\ntx@sltrue`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik curiously miktex has the identical package version, but there the line reads ``\global\newif\ntx@sl\global\ntx@sltrue%` I wonder how he managed to get different versions into the texsystem.

Comment: Same error appears to be in `ot1ntxtlf`.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik but `\global\newif` doesn't do anything sensible

Comment: The issue has been resolved with the latest update to `newtx` now available from CTAN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In addition to egreg's explanation, you can add this to your document before loading `newtxtext` to work around the problem while the package isn't updated:

```latex
\makeatletter
\AddToHook{file/before/t1ntxtlf.fd}{\let\ntx@sltrue\fi}
\AddToHook{file/after/t1ntxtlf.fd}{\def\ntx@sltrue{\let\ifntx@sl\iftrue}}
\makeatother
%
\usepackage{newtxtext}
```

This hack will change the definition of `\ntx@sltrue` in the `t1ntxtlf.fd` file to force the balancing of the conditionals, and then restore its meaning after the file ends.

Comment: I used same temporary fix for `ot1ntxtlf.fd`, pending the updates at CTAN. The fixes are working fine with my document.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE

Version 1.653 (released 2021-05-24) of `newtx` has fixed the issue using the simpler

```
\@ifundefined{ifntx@sl}{\let\ifntx@sl\iftrue}{}
```

because, after further analysis, it was realized that the conditional is only needed locally.

### Original answer

The file `t1ntxtlf.fd` got changed in version 1.1 by adding

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ntx@sltrue\endcsname\relax
  \global\newif\ntx@sl\global\ntx@sltrue%
\fi
```

and a hot fix was released very soon with the lines changed to

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ntx@sltrue\endcsname\relax
  \global\newif\ifntx@sl\global\ntx@sltrue%
\fi
```

See http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtlf.fd?r1=37185&r2=59238 and http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/newtx/t1ntxtlf.fd?r1=59238&r2=59277

This can explain why on MiKTeX there is no apparent problem (but there is a problem nonetheless): TeX Live has the hot fix, but MiKTeX doesn't. As you see, the letters `if` at the beginning were missing in the “hot-fixed” version.

A new conditional should *never* be defined inside a conditional, not without great care anyway. The idea is to check whether `\ifntx@sl` is defined when the `.fd` file is read in and, if not, to define it. But what happens when the conditional is defined? Let's see a simpler example:

```
%\newif\iffoo
\expandafter\ifx\csname footrue\endcsname\relax
  \newif\iffoo\footrue
\fi
```

This works. But if we remove the comment in front of `\newif\iffoo` it doesn't, because the conditional returns false (since `\footrue` is not `\relax`) and so the true text is skipped, but keeping track of conditionals, so the `\fi` is matched to `\ifoo` and not to `\ifx`.

There is an additional problem here: `.fd` files are read inside a group for various technical reasons, so the conditional should be globally defined. However, `\global\newif` fails the target. Indeed, we can examine the definition of `\newif`

```
% latex.ltx, line 1216:
\def\newif#1{%
  \count@\escapechar \escapechar\m@ne
    \let#1\iffalse
    \@if#1\iftrue
    \@if#1\iffalse
  \escapechar\count@}
```

and `\global` will just make global the assignment `\count@=\escapechar`, which is not particularly useful and is actually wrong, although almost harmless.

I'm not sure why the initial check in the `.fd` file is deemed necessary: the package `newtxtext` defines `\ifntx@sl`, so the conditional will *always* return false, independently on whether the option `trueslanted` is passed to the package.